# How to enable warning days for SCHEDULED items in the org-mode agenda?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

**Q:** is there a way to enable warning days for `SCHEDULED` items in addition to `DEADLINE` items in `org-mode`?

One may set `org-deadline-warning-days` to have `DEADLINE` items show up a default number of days before the deadline in the agenda, or one may do it on a case-by-case basis by adding, eg, `-3d` to the `DEADLINE` timestamp.  Is there a way to get an analogous warning on `SCHEDULED` items as well?

Unless I missed it, there does not appear to be anything like `org-scheduled-warning-days`, and the `-3d` gambit does not appear to get `SCHEDULED` items to show up early in the agenda.

Comment: It looks like the opposite is true with scheduled days, i.e., using `-3d` would *delay* the appearance of a scheduled item for 3 days rather than setting an early warning:  http://orgmode.org/manual/Deadlines-and-scheduling.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but sadly, neither `-3d` nor `+3d` appears to provide the desired functionality (give warnings ahead of time, not delaying its inclusion in the agenda).

Comment: Assuming that you are able to obtain a result based on the built-in feature (i.e., *delay* scheduled items), then it is just a matter of finding that portion of the code and tweaking the mathematical calculation so that it displays the items *before* instead of *after*.  I would start with looking at `org-agenda-get-scheduled` to see whether that gives you any ideas.  My guess is that it would be necessary to borrow functionality from `org-agenda-get-deadlines` so that the scheduled date appears on the due date *and* also *before* as a warning.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution (work-around) would be to create two entries: one for the SCHEDULED item itself, and a second one created as a DEADLINE. This one would trigger the warning in the Agenda.